# Radiation diagram of dipole

Tags: diagrams

I would like to realize the radiation diagram of the dipole half-wave on latex but I can't find the good program. May I have the solution or an help please.

I'd like something realize this,
[image]

And something like this without arrows
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The purpose of this site is to exchange information on LaTeX codes. So most of the users here expect you to post some code that shows what you've tried. For newcomers this requirement is sometimes waived but I must say that I do not quite understand what you want to draw. Ti*k*Z comes with a decoration `expanding waves` (see p. 581 of the pgfmanual) and one can draw dipoles with pgfplots, say. Could you perhaps add a sketch of what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for illustration should suffice the following sketch (copied from one of the mine lecture notes):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 0pt,
     circ/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=22mm,
                    node contents={}},
every pin/.style = {align=center}
                    ]
  \node (n1) [circ];
  \node (n2) [circ,right=of n1,
              pin=60:Field\\ Strength];
  \draw [dash dot]
        (n1.north -| n1.east) -- (n1.south -| n1.east)
        node[below] {Side view};
  \draw [thick]
        ($(n2.east)+(2, 0.1)$) -| ++ (0.2, 1)
        ($(n2.east)+(2,-0.1)$) -| ++ (0.2,-1)
        node[below] {Short Dipole};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:** an approximation of provided images ...

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 0pt,
circ/.style args = {#1/#2}{circle, draw=#1, fill=#1!30, semitransparent,
                    minimum size=#2,
                    node contents={}},
   circ/.default = gray/22mm,
every pin/.style = {pin distance=9mm, align=center},
      arr/.style = {ultra thick, red, -{Triangle[bend]},
                    shorten <=-5mm, shorten >=-5mm}
                    ]
  \foreach \R in {0.25,0.5,...,1}
  \draw[very thin, dashed, gray] (0,0) circle[radius=\R*22mm];
  \foreach \ang in {0,30,...,330}
  \draw[very thin, dashed, gray] (0,0) -- (\ang:2.2)
    node[font=\footnotesize,pos=1.15] {\ang};
%
  \node (n0) [circ=cyan/33mm, 
              pin=75:Field Strength of\\ the isotropic antenna];
  \node (n1) [circ, left];
  \node (n2) [circ,right,
              pin=30:Field Strength\\ of a dipole];
%
  \draw[arr]    (n0.105) to [bend right=45] (n1.120); 
  \draw[arr]    (n0.290) to [bend right=45] (n2.300);
%
  \node (n3) [draw,minimum size=2mm,pin=330:baloon] at (0,5) {};
  \draw[{Bar[]Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[]Bar[]}] 
                ($(n3.north)+(-2.3,0.2)$) -- 
        node[above] {$\lambda/2$}
                ($(n3.north)+(2.3,0.2)$);
  \draw[ultra thick]    
                (n3.west) -- ++ (-2.2,0)
                (n3.east) -- ++ ( 2.2,0);
  \draw[double=gray!20,double distance=1mm, very thin] 
                (n3.south) -- coordinate[pin=165:coax] ++ (0,-2.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks !!!
And do you know how can I add the diagram of the isotropic antenna behind the diagram of the dipole like we can see on internet ? This is just to compare both antenna.

Comment: @Aurélien, this is possible, however, that i can do this at least you need to provide me a link to the picture which you have in mind.